Isekai where the guy is betrayed and he puts all the speed stats
I'm not sure, but I think he went to this world with his school room and after a while in some cave he was betrayed by a girl, he found like a phone that spoke to a guy who left his message all over the area new, he puts all the statuses up to speed and in the end he faces this girl who betrayed him before returning to his world, time passes differently outside

Is this a manga?

https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/kanzen-kaihi-healer-no-kiseki has all of the points in Evasion, but otherwise doesn't match.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Is this Dungeon Seeker...?

One day, Junpei Takeda, a high school student, was summoned to another world by a "god" on a whim, along with a delinquent, Shota Kido, and Junpei's childhood friend, Noriko Tatsumiya. They thought they were summoned as heroes, but for some reason, Junpei's status was worse than that of a villager. On top of that, he was pushed into a monstrous labyrinth with zero survival rate by those traitors. Junpei was almost ready to die in this desperate situation, but he came up with a clever plan to recover from the situation. The weakest dungeon seeker has found a way to explore the labyrinth and begun to take revenge on the traitors!

A Japanese high school student named Junpei is summoned to another world, along with four male classmates (who've been bullying him) and his childhood friend, Noriko.
He ends up being betrayed by Noriko (who sides with one of the bullies) and kicked into a 'Sacrificial Labyrinth,' in which time moves much slower than it does on the outside.
As he progresses through the labyrinth, he find a series of smartphone-shaped 'letters' from a previous adventurer, who advises him on how to escape the labyrinth alive.



And after defeating the first monster he encounters, he earns 885 status points and dumps all those points into his evasion stat, increasing it from 5 to 890.



He eventually meets Noriko again, clears the labyrinth, and returns to Japan.
